How to get CacheStatistics attributes in latest ehcache version 3.10.8
I am upgrading net.sf.ehcache ehcache from 2.10.6 to org.ehcache ehcache with 3.10.8 jakarta as classifier.
URL configUrl = getClass().getResource("/ehcache.xml");
CachingProvider cachingProvider = Caching.getCachingProvider("org.ehcache.jsr107.EhcacheCachingProvider");
javax.cache.CacheManager cacheManager = cachingProvider.getCacheManager(configUrl.toURI(), getClass().getClassLoader());
for (String cacheName : cacheManager.getCacheNames()) {
}

In many places , I am retrieveing cacheName with help of above code.
Is there any alternative get all the cache names if it creating memory leak issue?
In old code, we using below these attributes to display healthcheck of cache.
Map<String, Object> cacheMap = new TreeMap<String, Object>();
CacheConfiguration cacheConfig = cache.getCacheConfiguration();
CacheStatistics statistics = new CacheStatistics(cache);
cacheMap.put("DiskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds", cacheConfig.getDiskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds());
cacheMap.put("DiskPersistent", cacheConfig.isDiskPersistent());
cacheMap.put("Eternal", cacheConfig.isEternal());
cacheMap.put("MaxElementsInMemory", cacheConfig.getMaxElementsInMemory());
cacheMap.put("MaxElementsOnDisk", cacheConfig.getMaxElementsOnDisk());
cacheMap.put("MemoryStoreEvictionPolicy", cacheConfig.getMemoryStoreEvictionPolicy());
cacheMap.put("OverflowToDisk", cacheConfig.isOverflowToDisk());
cacheMap.put("TimeToIdleSeconds", cacheConfig.getTimeToIdleSeconds());
cacheMap.put("TimeToLiveSeconds", cacheConfig.getTimeToLiveSeconds());
cacheMap.put("CacheHits", statistics.getCacheHits());
cacheMap.put("CacheMisses", statistics.getCacheMisses());
cacheMap.put("InMemoryHits", statistics.getInMemoryHits());
cacheMap.put("ObjectCount", statistics.getMemoryStoreObjectCount());
cacheMap.put("OnDiskHits", statistics.getOnDiskHits());

What are alternative in 3.10.8. I could get few attributes but not all.
Is there any doc/example which can help me?
Any help on this appreciated.
Thanks,
